# Detect intersecting triangles in geometries

Tags: algorithm, geometry, mesh, intersection

I have two geometries. Each of them consists of triangular elements (we can see them as a result of a triangulation).

Let us call G1 the first geometri and G2 the second. Also let's call t_{1,i} the triangles of G1 and t_{2,i} the triangles of G2.

I would need an algorithm which given G1 and G2 in input, return all the couples (t_{1,k}, t_{2,w}) if these two triangles intersects.

Here a picture just to make more clear what I mean for intersecting triangles.

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: If you don't have any restrictions for the geometries, like they are convex then you can try brute force all possible pairs. Or you can implement some space partition to improve performance.

Comment: Yes the intersection will be all convex! I only have triangles in my meshes. And, i would have prefered to not go with brute force, since I have to make a lot of examples where for each couple of mesh I compute intersections